# Subsets and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, supremum-and-infimum

We have that $X$ is a set of all sequences $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$. Now we introduce $Y$ as a set of all sequences $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n| < \infty$.

I have to show that $Y \subseteq X$ and need to find a sequence  $\{x_n\}$ that belongs only to $X$ and not $Y$.

To show that $Y \subseteq X$, all elements of $Y$ should be contained in $X$. I know that the sum of the absolute value of the sequences is smaller than $\infty$ which means that it's converging.
Is this where I need to use *Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem* to show that $Y \subseteq X$.

For the second part of the problem, would the sequence that only belongs to $X$ and not $Y$ be the supremum of $X$.

Comment: For the second part, there are many sequences whose values go to zero but the terms sum to infinity, you are asked to give one such example.

Comment: For the first part, Bolzano-Wierstrass deals with something else.  Here you just show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n|<\infty$ then $y_n\rightarrow 0$, you can use contradiction if you like.  Or write $y_n$ as the difference of two partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, the inequality

$$
|y_k| \leq \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} |y_n|
$$

is useful. For the second part, the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is always a good place to start looking.